# GetsessionId formula not working in joined report

Tags: session, joined-reports

I have a formula field on Opportunitu using the getsessionid() formula. 
I added this field to a report. 
This works fine in a tabular report but not working in a joined report type - the session Id returned is "NULL_SESSION_ID".

Anyone can help and say why this abnormality and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bug in SFDC. Better you get in touch with SFDC support. As a temporary workaround, I created a text field on Opportunity and a trigger or WF rule which copies the formula field value to the text field and used the text field on reports. Worked.

Thanks,
Shailesh

Comment: It won't hold when session Id is changed.